# ¿Evitar el ingreso de un usuario inactivo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Buen día para todos, agradezco a todos aquellos que se toman la molestia de leer mi inquietud

Mi problema es el siguiente, necesito evitar que un usuario inactivo ingres al sistema, el campo que estoy evaluando es state, de la tabla users, donde 1 es activo y 2 inactivo

Probé lo siguiente:

```
 public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
 
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password','state');
 //verifico que esta llegando, pero no sucede nada
    return $credentials;

    if (Auth::attempt(['state' => 1])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('index')->with('notification',
            'Su usuario actualmente se encuentra inactivo, contacte al administrador');
    }
    
}
```

Me base en la documentación de laravel, el anterior código esta ubicado en el controlador LoginController
sin embargo no veo ningún resultado o error alguno, estuve probando con un post donde el middleware de Authenticate.php tiene lo siguiente:

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->state==2) {
        // usuario con sesión iniciada pero inactivo

        // cerramos su sesión
        Auth::check()->logout();

        // invalidamos su sesión
        $request->session()->invalidate();

        // redireccionamos a donde queremos
        redirect('/')->with('notification','Usuario inactivo, contacté al administrador.');
    }
```

Y sigo sin tener algún resultado, el sistema permite ingresar al usuario con estado inactivo (state=2), podrían colaborarme, les agradezco.

Comment: Ve a la sección **especificando condiciones adicionales** y ahi esta la respuesta a tu pregunta sobre como tratar esto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: de ahí me base para hacer el primer código, sin embargo no hace nada ----> https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Créeme ya lo intente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu loginController debes sobreescribir los metodos **credentials** y **sendFailedLogin**

```
    protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        return ['email' => $request->{$this->username()}, 'password' => $request->password, 'state' => 1];
    }
```

y

```
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {

        if ( !User::where('email', $request->email)->first() ) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    $this->username() => 'El usuario no es correcto',
                ]);
        }

        if ( !User::where('email', $request->email)->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))->first() ) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'password' => 'Error de autentificación',
                ]);
        }


        if ( !User::where('email', $request->email)->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))->where('state', 1)->first() ) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'password' => 'Usuario desactivado',
                ]);
        }

    }
```

OJO: En sendFailedLoginResponse, puedes especificar el mismo mensaje de respuesta para el error de email y password y así previenes que sepan que el usuario "X" existe pero la password esta mal. O si quieres especificas mensajes diferentes y así consigues granularizar los mensajes de error dependiendo de si esta mal el usuario, la password o tiene el usuario desactivado.

Comment: Estupendo, tu código funciono, pero esperaba algo mas corto y claro, pero mil gracias amigo!